# Integral of sign function of sum of sine and cosine

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

what would have to be done in the case when $x = a \cdot sin(t) + b \cdot cos(t)$ and one has to evaluate the integral $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} sign(x) dt$? In the case that i dont know the values of $a$ and $b$ only that they are real and positive. I understand that for the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ : $sign(x)=1$ but for the interval $[\pi/2, \pi]$ the $sin()$ function is positive but the $cos()$ function is negative so how do i determine the sign? Thank you.

Comment: You could determine the root of $x(t)=a*\sin(t)+b*\cos(t)$ by solving $\tan(t)=-\frac{b}{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

A useful trick is to write $ a = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \cos \theta $ and $b = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin \theta $ for some $\theta$ to be determined.  This will always be possible - think of polar coordinates.

Then
$$ a \sin t + b \cos t = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} ( \cos \theta \sin t + \sin\theta \cos t)  = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin(t + \theta) $$ and the sign now becomes clear, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

The sign is that of

$$\sin\left(x+\phi\right)$$ where $\phi$ is in the first quadrant and $\tan\phi=\dfrac ba$.

$$0\le x+\phi\le\pi\land 0\le x\le \pi\iff 0\le x\le \pi-\phi$$

and the integral of the sign is

$$(\pi-\phi)-\phi.$$

[image]